# Is it possible to add a custom `ChannelInboundHandler` in Micronaut?

Tags: ssl, netty, micronaut

I would like to add a custom `ChannelInboundHandler` in my Micronaut service so that I can listen for the `SslHandshakeCompletionEvent` produced after a TLS handshake has been attempted.

I seem to be able to add a `ChannelOutboundHandler` simply enough by annotating it with `@Singleton`, however when I try to do the same with a `ChannelInboundHandler`, it does not seem to be added to the pipeline.

What's the correct way to do this?

**Edit**

This looks promising: https://docs.micronaut.io/snapshot/guide/index.html#nettyPipeline

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an implementation of `BeanCreatedEventListener<ChannelPipelineCustomizer>`, and provide an implementation of the `onCreated` method, e.g.

```
    @Override
    public ChannelPipelineCustomizer onCreated(BeanCreatedEvent<ChannelPipelineCustomizer> event) {
        ChannelPipelineCustomizer customizer = event.getBean();

        if (!customizer.isServerChannel()) {
            customizer.doOnConnect(pipeline -> {
                pipeline.addAfter(
                    ChannelPipelineCustomizer.HANDLER_HTTP_CLIENT_CODEC,
                    "my-handler",
                    new MyChannelInboundHandler()
                );
                return pipeline;
            });
        }

        return customizer;
    }
```

Then, in your `MyChannelInboundHandler` class, implement the `userEventTriggered` method and listen to the `SslHandshakeCompletionEvent.SUCCESS` event. You can then make some assertions on e.g. the public key of some of the certificates in the chain if you're doing `HPKP`.